# How to get Windows Server 1709 and 1803 with Containers on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2016

So I found this announcement from Amazon that they have Windows Server 2016 build 1709 and 1803:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/05/amazon-ec2-now-offers-windows-server-version-1709-and-1803-amis/

Great - but when I search AWS Marketplace for "Windows Server 1709" or anything "Windows Server" related the 1709 / 1803 releases are NOT there anywhere.  Note that 1709 is a major update to Windows Server 2016 and is not the same thing as Windows Server 2016.

Does anyone know where to find this AMI?  I really need 1709 or later due to container compatability issues.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not specify what region you are using. Perhaps they are not available in ALL regions, but you can always copy an AMI to your region. Here are the AMI IDs for two regions. Both can be found in the AWS Console Choose AMI screen.

**For the US-West-2 (Oregon) region:**

Microsoft Windows Server 1709 with Containers - ami-09e1069e8977beaaf

Microsoft Windows Server 1803 with Containers - ami-08d548200f7232435

**US-East-1**

Microsoft Windows Server 1709 with Containers - ami-04aa9dd58d1277860

Microsoft Windows Server 1803 with Containers - ami-0a730289c7c16e141

Comment: Thanks.  I am using US-East-1.  I don't see those in AWS Marketplace.  Is that a different set of content than in the EC2 Choose AMI Screen?

Comment: These AMIs are available in the AWS Console when you click Launch Instance. In your browser type CTRL-F and enter part of the AMI ID.